# Rewrite URL with .htaccess for 2 parameters with 1 as page and 2nd as $_GET value

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using xampp for making website.

1)I want to redirect `public_html/home` to `public_html/index.php?page=home` and

2)I want to redirect `public_html/about/1` to `public_html/index.php?page=about&id=1`

Following code changes `public_html/abc` to `public_html/index.php?page=abc`

But I couldn't get code for point number 2 above

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Try `RewriteRule (.*)/([0-9]+) index.php?page=$1&id=$2`. Personally, I would rather recommend you to use a router for this. Then all the routes are included in the application itself, instead of having application specific logic on the web server. It also makes your code more portable.

Comment: it worked for public_html/furniture/1 and redirected to public_html/index.php?page=furniture&id=1
 But didn't worked for public_html/furniture to redirect to public_html/index.php?page=furniture

Comment: To clarify, you need both rules `(.*) index.php?page=$1` and `(.*)/([0-9]+) index.php?page=$1&id=$2`.

Comment: http://localhost/furniture/public_html/furniture/1    REDIRECTED ME TO
Warning: require(../pages/index.php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp7\htdocs\furniture\public_html\index.php on line 8


AND
http://localhost/furniture/public_html/furniture  worked